# MAMP не отправляет тестовое письмо на почту

Tags: php, mamp

установил mamp для отправки тестового письма на почту.
Скрипт отрабатывает, все формы работают как надо, но есть две проблемы:
1 - порт 8888 занят, попробуйте другой порт. Я изменяю порт в настройках, но проблема не решается.
2 - само письмо не приходит на почту, то есть, форму заполнил, появилось окно благодарности, а вот письмо на почту не приходит.
Скрипт php рабочий 100%, в консоли во вкладке network так же ничего не отображается, то есть проблема в mamp.

Каким способом можно это решить? Сижу третий день, не могу найти ответ.

Буду очень признателен за ответ.

---

скриншот с ошибкой в логах....

Comment: А что в логах написано?

Comment: да дофига чего) сейчас скину скрин

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FBV1SC7JOokfSR5IpmNWxUf15EkYCDSn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FP6EgZkjLSrVZE941HZ0AK9kDMWrifax/view?usp=sharing

Comment: доступ же закрыт)